# Объединение таблиц: Join(ы) или обычным способом?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Читаю про `Join`(ы) и вижу такие примеры: 
Вот пример без `Join`(a)

```
SELECT prod_name, vend_name, prod_price, quantity FROM OrderItems, Products, Vendors
WHERE Products.vend_id = Vendors.vend_id
AND OrderItems.prod_id = Products.prod_id
AND order_num = 20007;
```

А вот пример с ним:

```
SELECT vend_name, prod_name, prod_price 
FROM Vendors INNER JOIN Products
ON Vendors.vend_id = Products.vend_id;
```

Хотел спросить в чем отличие? Что первый что второй запрос выдают один и тот же результат. Помню на лекциях говорили, что: Чем меньше кода тем лучше. В данном случае вижу что с `INNER JOIN` кода меньше поэтому он лучше? Есть ли различия по производительности? Почему все `JOIN`(ы) используют, а не первый пример допустим?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL - это декларативный язык. Вы просто говорите, что вы хотите получить, а СУБД уже сама решает, как ваши данные достать. Оба запроса описывают один и тот же результат.

> Помню на лекциях говорили, что: Чем меньше кода тем лучше.

Это спорно. В моем окружении программисты придерживаются мнения, что код должен быть максимально понятным. Отсюда, краткость - не всегда хорошо.

> В данном случае вижу что с INNER JOIN кода меньше поэтому он лучше?

Я склонен считать, что `inner join` лучше, т.к. с ним запрос более понятен. Это становится особенно актуально, когда в запросе таблиц 5 и больше.

> Есть ли различия по производительности?

Часто движок СУБД изменяет запросы, по этому правильно сравнивать производительность запросов не по их тексту, а по плану запроса.

Answer (score 3):

```
from table1, table2
```

Это полный эквивалент для

```
from table1 cross join table2
```

Из-за дополнительных условий в `where` может быть похож на `inner join`, но в первую очередь это декартово произведение множеств (`Cartesian product`).

По стилю написания - это вопрос холивара и стандартов кодирования на проекте. Здесь не может быть однозначного ответа.

В то же время синтаксис `from table1, table2` - это только декартово произведение, тогда как синтаксис `join` даёт больше возможностей. Например, `left join` через декартово произведение не сделать.

---

По производительности - планировщик СУБД в любом случае перепишет запрос так как ему больше понравится опираясь на свою статистику значений и модель cost-based оптимизатора. У postgresql вообще нет какого-то абстрактного оператора объединения таблиц. Потому что даже такую простую штуку как inner join для двух таблиц postgresql может выполнить минимум 6 разными способами: используя алгоритмы nested loops, hash или merge join и для прямого и для обратного порядка объединения таблиц. Затем помножить число возможных планов выполнения на возможности параллельного выполнения. Затем помножить на возможности выполнения по индексам (3 разных способа) или последовательным чтением всей таблицы. И на вопрос производительности запроса может ответить только конкретный `explain (analyze,buffers)`

Answer (score 0):

Оператор `JOIN` проще и понятнее, чем `WHERE` с кучей условий. Плюс `JOIN`, как правило, выполняется быстрее. Но, для того чтобы точно сказать о производительности нужно смотреть план выполнения конкретного запроса в конкретной СУБД.

Comment: Ни разу не сталкивался с ситуацией, когда `join` выполнился быстрее, чем такой же запрос с `where`. Хотя возможно это вызвано тем, что в работе у меня редко встречаются запросы с `where`. При этом речь о `dwh`, все запросы тяжелые и разница должна была бы быть заметна не вооруженным взглядом